# jQuery script doesn't work without an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, dialog, click

I have an script that uses jquery, but i have a problem in the next part:

```
        $("#botonAgregar").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: $(this).attr('href'),
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#dialogDiv").html(html);
                    $("#dialogDiv").dialog('open');
                }
            });
            alert();
            $("a[type='submit']").click(function() {
                var formName = $(this).attr("nombreform");
                var formSelector = "form#" + formName;
                $(formSelector).submit();
            });
            return false;
        });
```

It works as it is, but if i remove the "alert();" line it doesnt add the click event to $("a[type='submit']") objects. What could be wrong?

Comment: Ajax is async. The success callback is there for a reason, use it.

Comment: Imagine that this ajax requests takes three seconds. On second one, you send the ajax request. On second two, you're binding a click event to all anchor tags that have a type attribute set to submit, then on second three you're adding an anchor element with a type attribute set to submit. Adding the alert makes the event binding happen after the element was added because of how long it took you to click ok.

Answer (score 1):

> it doesnt add the click event to $("a[type='submit']") objects

Yes it does.  However, if more of those elements are being added during the AJAX call then you'll need to re-add the handler to those new elements after those are added to the DOM.  Currently you're not doing that because the code *after* your call to `.ajax()` is happening *before* the AJAX call completes.  This is because AJAX is, by definition, asynchronous.  It's *possible* for the AJAX call to complete before later code is executed, but it is not guaranteed.  (And in the case of code that's immediately after it, it's highly unlikely.)

Your `success` handler is called when the AJAX call completes, so that would be an opportune time to do this:

```
$("#dialogDiv").html(html);
$("#dialogDiv").dialog('open');
$("a[type='submit']").click(function() {
    var formName = $(this).attr("nombreform");
    var formSelector = "form#" + formName;
    $(formSelector).submit();
});
```

However, **there is a much better way to do this**.

One of the problems with the approach you have is that you're going to re-add the handler to the same elements over and over.  You're also adding the same handler to many elements, when you really only need one.  Take a look at [the jQuery `.on()` function](http://api.jquery.com/on/).  Essentially what it does is add a single handler to a common parent element of the target elements, and then filter the events based on the target element selector.  So you only need to add the handler once:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'a[type=submit]', function () {
        var formName = $(this).attr('nombreform');
        var formSelector = 'form#' + formName;
        $(formSelector).submit();
    });
});
```

In this case I'm using `document` as the common parent, though any other parent will work.  (The `body` tag, a `div` which contains all of the target elements, etc.  It just needs to be a common parent element which doesn't change throughout the life of the DOM.)

Comment: *"Yes it does."* not if they don't exist, :p

Comment: @KevinB: It doesn't make that distinction.  It adds the handler to all matched elements at the time the code executes.  If there aren't any matched elements then, well, there aren't any events to handle.

Comment: Thanks, once I remembered it´s "asynchronous" everything is obvious. As I only have one or two a[type=submit] elements in the DOM theres no problem handling the event any time the dialog opens.